# draggable, resizable text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to create re-sizable and drag-able input element. I create it by clicking on my div (primary id) . However when i use re-sizable , it creates something empty that is re-sizable. Drag-able doesn't work , probably because of text input is clickable. Is there a way how to override it to do move on mouse move and select it on just mouse click?

```
document.getElementById("primary").onmousedown = function(event) {
    div = document.createElement("INPUT");
    div.setAttribute("id", "text");
    div.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    div.style.position = "absolute";
    div.style.resize="both";
    x1 = Math.round(event.clientX);
    y1 = Math.round(event.clientY);
    div.style.left = x1 + "px";
    div.style.top = y1 + "px";
    div.style.width =500+"px";
    div.style.height = 50+"px";         
    document.getElementById("primary").appendChild(div);
    $(div).resizable().draggable();
    }
```

Comment: Any reason why you can't just use a [textarea](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp)?

Comment: I could but it will only solve problem of re-sizable , input was little better for my furture problems.